# Who was Lakulesh

Tags: shiva, kalpa

In which kalpa [Lakulesh](https://www.krishnakutumb.com/blog/lakulesh/) was present, was it  the current kalp ? as the devo ke dev mahadev serial doesn't give this information. The serial also shows that  he did penance through multiple kalpa.  How a human can stay alive for multiple kalpa ?

Comment: Never scriptures mention that Shiva time travelled for him. So, Lakulesh is just a folk character.